# Why this code whit pre tag doesn't scroll?

Tags: html, css, pre

In my blog the `code` tag within the `pre` tag doesn't scroll. Why?

HTML Code:

```
<pre class="source-code"><code>sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential libgcrypt11-dev libjson0-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat1-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev binutils-dev</code></pre>
```

Css:

```
pre.source-code {
  font-family: Andale Mono, Lucida Console, Monaco, fixed, monospace; 
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you prepare jsFiddle with your problem?

Comment: Urm, it works here - http://jsfiddle.net/HFQUD/

Comment: [link of my blog](http://www.epclinux.com/) I've tried even in two browser... I have seen that works in jsFiddle.

Comment: @nunzio13n your blog doesn't contain a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: There are no pre elements in the source code of that page.

Comment: @Quentin: Look in an article?

Comment: sorry I give you the link of the blog, not of the post... [link post](http://www.epclinux.com/2013/03/synchronize-google-drive-and-linux-with.html)

Comment: now I have added `white-space: nowrap;` and the scroll works, but there is a problem with the new line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `overflow-wrap: normal` to prevent the line from automatically wrapping. Not sure why it was on `word-break` by default.

Comment: Thank you, now It's perfect. I'm using a template from blogger, perhaps in the template is `word-break` as default

Comment: @nunzio13n: Maybe, the Web Tools didn't show me what declared it.